# Retrieve JSON Data In Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am retrieving [json](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) data via [http.get](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp), my problem is that I cannot get a specific values of my key in [typescript](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/index.htm).

The data I am returning is in the format (json):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Albany",
        "manufacture": "Albany Superior Low Gi Sliced Brown Seed Bread 700g",
        "price": 15.49,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Breads",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ..."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Blue Ribbon",
        "manufacture": "Blue Ribbon Brown Plus Low Gi Bread 700g",
        "price": 13.99,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Breads",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg..."
    }
]
```

In Angular, my service is as below:

```
export class ProductService {

  prodType:ProductModel;
  productList:object;

  prodList: Array<ProductModel> = [];
  prodMap: Map<number, ProductModel>;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

    getAllProducts(): Array<ProductModel>{
    this.http.get<Array<ProductModel>>('/product/service/send/all/products').subscribe(
      data => {

        console.log( data );

      },
      error => {
        console.error("HTTP FAILURE ERROR!!!");
      }
    );
    return this.prodList;

  }

  getProductByType( productSearch:string ){

    this.productList = this.prodList.find( x=> x.getType() == productSearch);
    console.log( this.productList);
  }  
}
```

The ProductModel is as follows:

```
export class ProductModel {

    private id: number;
    private name: string;
    private manufacture: string;
    private price: number;
    private category: string;
    private type: string;
    private image: string;
    // get and setters
```

The million dollar question; let's say I would to search through my data for product types and only wanted to console-log products with type milk from my json data.

How would I do that? I have searched for similar solution, but they were unhelpful.

Comment: `console.log( data.filter(x => x.type== 'Milk') );` see [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: array.filter look at that

Answer (score 1):

First assign the HTTP result to your class member and then filter your datas and then console.log the filtered array items.

```
export class ProductService {

  prodType:ProductModel;
  productList:object;

  prodList: Array<ProductModel> = [];
  prodMap: Map<number, ProductModel>;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

    getAllProducts() {
    this.http.get<Array<ProductModel>>('/product/service/send/all/products').subscribe(
      datas => {

        this.prodList = datas;

      },
      error => {
        console.error("HTTP FAILURE ERROR!!!");
      }
    );    
  }

  getProductByType( productSearch:string ): Array<ProductModel>{

    let filteredProducts:Array<ProductModel> = this.prodList.filter(product => product.type == productSearch);

    filteredProducts.forEach(product=> console.log(product);

    return filteredProducts;

  }  
}
```

Comment: I modified my codes and receive this error in my browser: ERROR TypeError: product.getType is not a function

Comment: in TypeScript accessors are not formatted like get<MemberName> (the Java way) it's myObj.mymeber directly. 
What's the code you write to make the call ?

Comment: public getType(): string {
        return this.type;
    }

    public getImage(): string {
        return this.image;
    }

Comment: What seem's to be the problem?

Comment: Don't you call `getProductByType` before all datas are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the map and modify the response coming from the http get call and filter it before assigning it to the list . of if you want to separate the same then you need split the logic into two methods one to get the vanilla list and then filter the data on top of it

```
 getAllProducts(): Array<ProductModel>{
    return this.http.get<Array<ProductModel>>('/product/service/send/all/products').map(data => data.filter(value => value.type == 'milk')).subscribe() ;
  }
```